# Make an array with sum of elements equal to a number k from an Vector of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have a vector with n arrays of integers (let's call it Arrays) and a number k. I must find a way to make a vector, let's call it Sol, with property that sum of all its elements is k and Sol[i] is from Arrays[i].
Ex:

First is n, second is k, then arrays.

input:

```html
3 10
1 2 3
2 5 7
4 6 8
```

console:

```html
2 2 6
```

I could simply use backtracking but is a giant complexity. I tried to make an algorithm that start from the bottom and for each point it combine points from below making list of possible solution like:

```html
3 10
1 2 3
2 5 7
4 6 8

ex for:
8 < 10, viable solution
6 < 10, viable solution
4 < 10, viable solution

7 + 8 = 15 < 10 false never check this path again
7 + 6 = 13 < 10 false never check this path again
...
```

Even if I do this, there are some situations for big complexity. I aim for O(m*k) complexity, where m is sum of lengths of all input Arrays.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    static Vector<Vector<Integer>> Arrays;
    static int Arrays_lenght;
    static int sum;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        Scanner data_in = new Scanner(new File("data.in"));
        Arrays_lenght = data_in.nextInt();
        sum = data_in.nextInt();

        Arrays = new Vector<>();
        data_in.nextLine();

        //read vectors
        for(int i = 0; i < numar_vectori; i++) 
        {
            String temp = data_in.nextLine();
            Scanner _temp = new Scanner(temp);
            Vector<Integer> temp_vector = new Vector<>();
            while (_temp.hasNext()) {
                temp_vector.add(_temp.nextInt());
            }
            Arrays.add(temp_vector);
        }

        Iterator<Vector<Integer>> itr = Arrays.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext())
            System.out.printf("%s\n", itr.next().toString());
    }
}
```

Here is my code from reading the input file in java. How can I make the Sol vector in O(m*k) complexity where m is sum of lengths of all input Arrays?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can I make the Sol vector in O(m*k) complexity where m is sum of lenghts of all input Arrays. Sorry if it wasn't clear. I will fix my post.

Comment: Have you considered dynamic programming? You will need storage array of size about k*n (depends on implementation)

Comment: read about it. Have no ideea how to implement. Some ideea of pseudocode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic programming solution (I assume that input array `A[][]` contains natural numbers):

Create 2D array `B[][]` - N lines, K+1 columns, fill with zeros.

```
for every element of the first input array el=A[0][ix] 
   set B[0][el] = ix+1  
  // incrementing is useful to separate filled entries from empty ones

for i = 1 to n-1
   for every element of i-th input array `el=A[i][ix]`:
       for every ik index in range 0..Sum-el   
          if B[i - 1, ik] is filled then 
              set B[i, ik + el] = ix+1

at the end:
if B[N-1, K] is filled
    unwind indexes of elements that produce needed sum
```

The second stage executes upto K times for every element of input matrix (except for the first array row), so time complexity is O(K*M).